# Conversion failed error when writing to C# DataTable using SQL select results

Tags: c#, sql

I am filling a datatable with Date, TimeSlot, FullName, and Availablity fields from a SQL DB.

I have a variable `private DateTime Sdate {get => dateTimePickerAppointment.Value;}` taking the date value from dateTimePicker object.

When I run the SqlCommand to get the data from the SQL table, it works fine until I enter a date with a day value greater than 12.

If the day value is greater than 12, I get the exception
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'`

I need some advice on how to fix this issue.

I tried using 'Convert' in the SQL SELECT statement to convert to date and string. It didn't work.

My date column in the SQL table is type: date

```
private DateTime Sdate {get => dateTimePickerAppointment.Value;}

case 6:
    MessageBox.Show("Specific Date required ", appSearch.ToString("X"));
    // define new SQL command cmdDB as new SQL Command (SELECT...........)
    SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(200)Date ,[TimeSlot],[FullName],[Availability] FROM [qryGPAppointmentsSchedule] WHERE Availability IS NULL and Date = '"  + Sdate + "'", con);

    try
    {
        //define a new SQL Data Adapter sda as a new SQL Data Adapter
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd6;// SQL Adapter selection = cmdDB


        DataTable dtAvailable = new DataTable();// defined new data table
        sda.Fill(dtAvailable);//SQL adapter is to fill dtAvailable
        dataGridViewAppointmentsAvailable.DataSource = cmd6;

        BindingSource aSource = new BindingSource();
        aSource.DataSource = dtAvailable;
        dataGridViewAppointmentsAvailable.DataSource = aSource;
        //sda.Update(dtAvailable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: the date formatting is likely different. if it is limited to 12 then it is probably expecting a month

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the issue, but I'm not sure what to convert: the SQL data or the C# variable

Comment: the c# variable should do it

Comment: From the query remove the single quotes which is taking the DateTime Object and converting to a string.  Instead make the DateTime a parameter so you are passing the date as a DateTime instead of a string.

Comment: It'll be a dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy issue by the sound of it. Check your application and database's culture settings are correct and also match each other, and match what you want your users to be using. (If you need to support multiple cultures then it gets more interesting...but that's another topic on its own). You should also be passing that DateTime into your query using proper [parameterised queries](https://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) (which also removes the risk of [SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com) as well). Creating SQL by simply joining strings together is dangerous.

Comment: can show example data of Sdate  and any Date column value

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly try below code :

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(200)Date ,[TimeSlot],[FullName],[Availability] FROM [qryGPAppointmentsSchedule] WHERE Availability IS NULL and Date = @dateInput", con);
cmd6.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateInput", Sdate));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion Touareg, but my datatable was empty.
I have narrowed the problem down to the difference between the date format in my SQL table yyyy-MM-dd (type: date) and the date format in the C# datatable MM/dd/yyyy. It seems that the SQL Select statement pulls the date value in as a string and it cannot be converted to the datatable format once the day value goes above 12. What I need to be able to do is change the default datatable date format to either yyyy-MM-dd or dd/MM/yyyy. How do I do this?